# Error MSB4044 The "RazorGenerate" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Version"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I get an error: The "RazorTagHelper" task failed unexpectedly.
It looks like the problem is that I have the latest version of ".NET" installed.

I tried several solutions to this problem but nothing worked for me.

- I added the system variable "DOTNET_HOST_PATH: dotnet"
- Added nugget Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor
- Installed ".NET Core 2.2 SDK"

Unfortunately, none of this helped me.

Here my csproj:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
 
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
     <UserSecretsId>aspnet-IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity-04C6939F-E672-4E56-B4A5-5F064EB67F23</UserSecretsId>
   </PropertyGroup>
 
 
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="3.10.10" />
     <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.5.3" />
     <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="2.5.3" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6" PrivateAssets="All" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="3.1.10" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
     <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.8.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
 
   <ItemGroup>
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
     <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
 
   <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
   </ItemGroup>
 
 </Project>
```

Comment: Input `cmd` in your windows search to open your `Command Prompt`,then input `setx DOTNET_HOST_PATH "%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\dotnet.exe"`,then close VS and restart.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor with this version Version="2.2.0"
Instead of version 3.1.10.

It works for me, I wish it may help you.